# JSON to CSV, skipping certain columns and re-ordering others - Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, csv, converters

I have a working script that nicely converts JSON files to CSV files, however I'm trying to edit the script to make some changes to the CSV file before saving, currently without any success.

Here is my current conversion script:

```
require 'csv'
require 'json'
require 'set'

def get_recursive_keys(hash, nested_key=nil)
  hash.each_with_object([]) do |(k,v),keys|
    k = "#{nested_key}.#{k}" unless nested_key.nil?
      if v.is_a? Hash
      keys.concat(get_recursive_keys(v, k))
    else
      keys << k
    end
  end
end

json = JSON.parse(File.open(ARGV[0]).read)
headings = Set.new
json.each do |hash|
  headings.merge(get_recursive_keys(hash))
end

headings = headings.to_a
CSV.open(ARGV[0] + '.csv', 'w') do |csv|
  csv << headings
  json.each do |hash|
    row = headings.map do |h|
      v = hash.dig(*h.split('.'))
      v.is_a?(Array) ? v.join(',') : v
    end
    csv << row
  end
end
```

Which I run with this command:

```
for file in directory/*; do ruby json-to-csv.rb "$file"; done
```

How can I edit this script to:

- Remove columns with certain headers, such as "score" and "original_name"
- (Re-order the remaining columns into alphabetical order from left-to-right) - if possible?

So far, everything I have tried completely breaks the script - where is the best place to start to make these changes?

Comment: Filter your json keys to remove certain columns. And use a sorted array to keep your output in order. What have you tried?

Comment: @knh190 I've been mostly working with the headings, but my filter seems to break the array every time. I've tried using a switch statement for "h" to filter out the columns I don't want after the "headings.map do |h|" - would it work better to focus on the json keys before the headings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code that works:

```
require 'csv'
require 'json'
require 'set'

def get_recursive_keys(hash, nested_key=nil)
  hash.each_with_object([]) do |(k,v),keys|
    # Col filter
    next if ["score", "original_name"].include? k
    k = "#{nested_key}.#{k}" unless nested_key.nil?
    if v.is_a? Hash
      keys.concat(get_recursive_keys(v, k))
    else
      keys << k
    end
  end
end

json = JSON.parse(File.open(ARGV[0]).read)
headings = Set.new
headings = get_recursive_keys(json)

headings = headings.to_a
# Header sorting
headings = headings.sort { |a, b| a <=> b }


CSV.open(ARGV[0] + '.csv', 'w') do |csv|
  csv << headings
  row = headings.map do |h|
    v = (h.split('.').length > 1) ? json.dig(*h.split('.')) : h
    v.is_a?(Array) ? v.join(',') : v
  end
  csv << row
end
```

I tested with this small json string: {"score": "12", "name": "Obi", "original_name": "Wan Kenobi", "something": {"sub_key": "Wuhu"} }

Comment: This is great! Works perfectly, I've also tweaked this to now only include headers that are specified instead of removing specific headers.